# Действительно ли throw сам по себе (т. е. без try) не работает?

Tags: javascript

Дело в том, что после совпавшего `throw` сразу прерывается исполнение и сразу переходим к `catch`.

```
console.log("128 THROW САМ ПО СЕБЕ БЕЗ TRY НЕ РАБОТАЕТ, хотя пример на странице 128 Фленагана есть");
var f132 = function (a,b) {
    if (a > b) {
        throw new Error ("заданная ошибка 1");  
        return a
    }
    if (a == b) {
        throw new Error ("заданная ошибка 2");
        return 7
    }
    else {
        throw new Error ("заданная ошибка 3");
        return 9
    } 
    //catch (er) { console.log (er); } //SyntaxError: catch without try =>9
}
console.log (f132(16,15));
```

Но как быть со страницей 128 учебника Фленагана, где утверждается, что так можно использовать `throw`?

[image: скриншот]

Comment: я понимаю, что throw работает везде, но перехватывается только в блоке try-catch. Если исключение не перехвачено на этом уровне, то оно выбрасывается на уровень выше.... т. е. при ненахождении уровнем выше catch и оно так не будет найдено, то исключение рассматривается как ошибка и о ней будет сообщено пользователю (то есть исполнения далее по коду при наличии throw и отсутствии на уровнях выше catch код "стопорится", выдаёт ошибку в консоли)? То есть throw  НЕ ИМЕЕТ смысла, если в коде нет catch?

Comment: То есть  throw , когда в коде нет catch, будет просто останавливать исполнение кода?

Comment: Достаточно набрать в Google _javascript throw_ и прочитать несколько статей по нему, чтобы разобраться. Например, [эту с MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw). И задавать вопросы только по действительно непонятным моментам.

Comment: `return` сразу после `throw` попросту бесполезен, потому что недостижим. Я сначала испугался, что это в книге такое написано (даже если для наглядности: мол, _до этого `return` код никогда не дойдёт_).

Answer (score 1):

Использование `throw` без `catch` - единственный разумный вариант в модульном коде, т.к. часто задача `throw` в функции - обработка ошибки способом, который определен вне этой функции.

```
function factorial(n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        throw new Error("Factorial argument must be non-negative");
    }
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}

try { // factorial ничего не знает об этом блоке
    console.log(factorial(-10));
} catch {
    console.log("Oops!");
}
```

Если `throw` выполнить вне `try`-блока, интерпретатор посчитает это системной ошибкой и обработает так, как считает нужным (зависит от того, браузер это или нода).

---

Прецедент из истории:

> Я сказал Деннису, что примерно половина кода, который я написал для Multics, была кодом обработки ошибок. Он ответил: «Мы всё это отбросили. Если произошла ошибка, у нас есть процедура под названием panic, и если она вызвана, компьютер зависает и вы кричите: „Эй, перезапустите его!“».

[wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_panic#.D0.98.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.8F)

Answer (score 0):

Конечно нет: throw прерывает исполнение кода.